# CSS width and height for modal window

Tags: html, css

I have a modal window in my code that has some img and some text. Images can be any aspect ratio, some horizontal (1000x700px) some vertical (300x600px). I'd like a modal window to be 70% width (and height not more than window height, like max-height:100%). But if it is a vertical image, I don't want it to be stretched to 70% width but have 100 (or 90%) height and the correct width. Here is what I have now. Thanks!

```
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
    border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: white;
    width: 70%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

HTML code

```
<div class="modal">
    <img src="" alt="image" class="opened_image">
    <div class="comment_zone"></div>
    <div class="send_comment">
        <input type="text" class="signin_input" placeholder="Comment plz..">
        <button class="signin_btn" type="submit" id="sendCommentBtn">Send</button>
    </div>
    <button class="close_img_btn" type="submit">&times;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide us your HTML code where you create modal?

Comment: @enucar HTML code provided )